# Julia fails to precompile packages ExcelFiles, Plots and JuMP

Tags: julia, precompile

I am a beginner with using Julia and I am trying to use the packages. However, when I try to use the packagegs Excelfiles, plots and JuMP. I use this code for the packages:
Pkg.add("JuMP")
using JuMP
I get the error: ERROR: Failed to precompile JuMP [4076af6c-e467-56ae-b986-b466b2749572] to C:\Users\yobbi.julia\compiled\v1.7\JuMP\jl_39BC.tmp. I already updated the packages, restarted my laptop, and downloaded Julia again but I keep getting this error. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
using Pkg
pkg"build JuMP"
```

This will either resolve your problem or show you errors in the package build process.

Please also note that "reinstalling" Julia usually not helps as Julia is keeping its files in the `.julia` folder.

Finally, your folder `C:\Users\yobbi.julia` looks fishy to me. Maybe it is a typo and it should be `C:\Users\yobbi\.julia` or you managed to misconfigure something with the `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` variable.